# How to detect spoiled or crashed images after upload

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, image-uploading, uploading

How i can detect spoiled images after upload?

Im using some code like this:

```
$imageSize = getimagesize($tmp_name);
if(!$imageSize ||  !in_array($imageSize['mime'], $allowMimeType)){
    $this->error = 'Bad Image';
    @unlink($tmp_name);
    return false;
}
$tn = imagecreatetruecolor(80, 80);
switch ($imageSize['mime']){
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $userphoto = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_name);// Error 1
    break;
    case 'image/png':
        $userphoto = imagecreatefrompng($tmp_name);// Error 1
    break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $userphoto = imagecreatefromgif($tmp_name);// Error 1
    break;
    case 'image/bmp':
        $userphoto = imagecreatefromwbmp($tmp_name);// Error 1
    break;
    default:
        $this->error = 'unknown image';
        @unlink($tmp_name);
        return false;
    break;
}
imagecopyresampled($tn, $userphoto, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 80, $width, $height);// Error 2
imagejpeg($tn,'images/userphoto/'.$this->username.'.jpg',100);
chmod('images/userphoto/'.$this->username.'.jpg', 0777);
@unlink($tmp_name);
USERPROFILE::updatePhotoByUsersId($this->username.'.jpg', $this->users_id);
```

But some time i give 2 error tandem,

1. at lines that have comment `// Error 1`

> imagecreatefromwbmp() [href='function.imagecreatefromwbmp'>function.imagecreatefromwbmp]: >'images/userphoto/4ff7db9800871.bmp' is not a valid WBMP file
>
> imagecreatefromgif() [href='function.imagecreatefromgif'>function.imagecreatefromgif]: >'images/usersphoto/4fe70bb390758' is not a valid GIF file

1. at line of comment `// Error 2`

> imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource
>   
>   I think its occurs because the file has damaged during uploading. If i'm right, how i can solve this problem? If not, What is the reason?

Comment: @Leo How it can help me? I cant find any things about ffmpeg else helpful to audio and video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you do any further processing, you should check the return value of [getimagesize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) .

If `getimagesize()` returns a `FALSE`, that means it has failed and something is wrong with the file, so you should terminate. Once the image passes this check, you can continue with your processing.

As for why you are getting `supplied argument is not a valid Image resource`, the explaination is simple: Most likely, the image stored in `$userphoto` is actually `FALSE` because `imagecreatefrompng()` and other `imagecreatefrom` functions have failed, returning a `FALSE`.

Solution: Check that the uploaded image is valid with `getimagesize()` before continuing.

Some possible reasons as to why the uploads are failing:

- Something is corrupting the images when they are written to the temp directory.
- User is uploading corrupted files.

---

Regarding `imagecreatefromwbmp()` failing, it is because gd does not support BMP files. You need to convert the BMP into a format gd can work with. For example, you can use [bmp2png](http://cetus.sakura.ne.jp/softlab/b2p-home/).

Comment: I have checked what `$imageSize = getimagesize($tmp_name);` return, i changed my post

Comment: can you `var_dump($tn)` and `var_dump($userPhoto)` to see what it returns?

Comment: So did you get `FALSE` for either `$tn` or `$userPhoto`?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I make mistake to copy `Error 1` first time, I change it to that it was.

Comment: Ah, so it is only failing on `imagecreatefromwbmp`. I think wbmp is for wireless bit maps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wbmp. Use something like bmp2png (http://cetus.sakura.ne.jp/softlab/b2p-home/) to convert the bmp to png first. Then work from there.

Comment: Ok, Tanks :), The last question, I put a new error to `Error 1`, is it the same problem?

Comment: From the looks of that error, it seems that there's something wrong with the GIF file. Can you check the file stored in the temp directory `'images/usersphoto/4fe70bb390758' `?

Comment: No, It was deleted automatically by `unlink` function, I have 19 error of wbmp and 2 gif, i got it, thanks for answer :)